# Use case diagram for a automated system

Tags: uml, use-case

i need realize an use case diagram for an automated system for quality check of some products through images,but i have very hard problem with it.When the process is started by an operator, the system must take image of product from a camera ,analyze the image with some algorithms, save the results  of analysis on database and send result to PLC. I going crazy. My solution proposed is in figure but i am sure that it isn't right. Thanks so much for your help and sorry for my bad english.I hope to have been clear.

First Solution:
[image]

Second Solution:
[image]

Example:

1. Operator click a button to start.
2. the system request the image to camera and camera send it.
   the System analyze image with some algorithms.
3. the system save all result. If the image of product is correct, not correct etc.
4. the system communicate to plc 0 if the image is correct , 1 otherwise

Comment: I would propose you add some reasonable details to your question and share your tries with us.

Comment: Question is unclear, I downvoted it.

Comment: @Bert Sorry,but it is my first post.I will try to be more specific.

Comment: You may want to investigate standard process flow chart symbols: https://www.programiz.com/article/flowchart-programming

Comment: No problem, this is much better

Comment: I have no idea why this has been closed as too broad. Definitely it isn't! Interestingly none of the close voters has any experience with use cases :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this is not the worst for a first approach.

A use case is about the added value(s) a system under consideration delivers to it(s) actor(s). So these are quite reasonable. WRT "start/end process" it looks a bit to flat as a UC description, but in the domain context it might be sufficient. Think about elaborating about what "process" in the context actually means (e.g. it could be "analysis" instead?).

P.S. since you edited while I was answering: the 2nd is probably better. Though you should avoid include/extend as they usually are a sign of functional analysis, which is not what UCs are meant for. I recommend reading Bittner/Spence about UCs (like always).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply and I will try to read Bittner/Spence.  I know that i should avoid include as i did, but I would like to make a clearer use case diagram.So It is wrong or i can let it ?.

Comment: You can let it as it is. Just do not over-use it.